# How to increment values for each key in dict?

Tags: python

In Python, how to iterate a `dict` and increment values of each key?

```
D = {k1:1, k2:2}
```

I want `D` to be `{k1:2, k2:3}`.

Comment: `for key,val in D.items()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have another solution for you, I hope it is useful.

```
for key in D:
    D[key] +=1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `dict` comprehension to increment each value, then assign it back

```
>>> {k: v+1 for k,v in D.items()}
{'k1': 2, 'k2': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either modify (also called "mutate") the dictionary D:

```
for k in D.keys():
    D[k] = D[k] + 1
```

Or you can create a new dictionary and re-assign D to it:

```
D = { k: v+1 for k, v in D.items() }
```

The difference will become apparent if something else points at D, or if D is very large and takes longer to re-create than to update in-place.

Answer (score 1):

```
D = {"k1":1, "k2":2}

for i in D:
  D[i] += 1

print(D)
```

Seems to do the trick, I wasnt sure on the k1 / k2 so i made them strings for testing